# Multiplying by a constant (T random variable)

Tags: distributions, random-variable, degrees-of-freedom, t-distribution, pivot

Suppose that $T$ has a distribution $t(n-1)$.

If we were to multiply $T$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, what would be the distribution of $\frac{T}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Get the t-distribution of the mean?

Comment: Originally, we have X1,...,Xn~N(mu, sigma^2). Given that T=(Xbar-mu)/(s/sqrt(n)) has a distribution t(n-1). Now, I am interested in knowing what the distribution of T/sqrt(n) would be.

Comment: I would like to know if T/sqrt(n) could be considered as a pivot, given that T itself is a pivot.

Answer (score 1):

If the PDF of a random variable $T$ is denoted as $f_T(t)$, then the PDF of $Z=\frac{T}{c}$ is $f_Z(z)=c*f_T(cz)$, where $c$ is a constant.